# Spring Boot data source

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I use Spring boot in my Application and trying to create a DataSource using UCP and stuck with the  following error. Similar question has already been posted but interested in knowing the reason with this configuration.

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.determineDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:104)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.buildDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:71)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:205)
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1887)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1845)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:852)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:845)
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:398)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:844)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:343)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1625)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1562)
... 143 more
```

But I have add the hibernate.dialect.

Aplication.java,

```
@Configuration //@EnableAutoConfiguration @ComponentScan @EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class }) @SpringBootApplication public class DialerApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(DialerApplication.class, args);
} }
```

DataSource file,

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef =     "dialerEntityManagerFactory", transactionManagerRef = "dialerTransactionManager", basePackages = { "com.nervytech.dialer.db.repository" })
public class ApplicationDataSource {

/** The Constant LOGGER. */
private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory
        .getLogger(ApplicationDataSource.class);

/** The Constant TEST_SQL. */
private static final String TEST_SQL = "select 1 from dual";

/** The pooled data source. */
private PoolDataSource pooledDataSource;

/** The environment. */
private Environment environment;

/** The Constant CONNECTION_WAIT_TIMEOUT_SECS. */
private static final int CONNECTION_WAIT_TIMEOUT_SECS = 300;

/**
 * Data source.
 * 
 * @return the pool data source
 */
@Bean(name = "dialerDataSource")
@Primary
public PoolDataSource dialerDataSource() {

    this.pooledDataSource = PoolDataSourceFactory.getPoolDataSource();
    final String databaseDriver = environment
            .getRequiredProperty("application.datasource.driverClassName");
    final String databaseUrl = environment
            .getRequiredProperty("application.datasource.url");
    final String databaseUsername = environment
            .getRequiredProperty("application.datasource.username");
    final String databasePassword = environment
            .getRequiredProperty("application.datasource.password");
    final String initialSize = environment
            .getRequiredProperty("application.datasource.initialSize");
    final String maxPoolSize = environment
            .getRequiredProperty("application.datasource.maxPoolSize");
    final String minPoolSize = environment
            .getRequiredProperty("application.datasource.minPoolSize");
    // final String poolName =
    // environment.getRequiredProperty("application.datasource.poolName");

    try {
        pooledDataSource.setConnectionFactoryClassName(databaseDriver);
        pooledDataSource.setURL(databaseUrl);
        pooledDataSource.setUser(databaseUsername);
        pooledDataSource.setPassword(databasePassword);
        pooledDataSource.setInitialPoolSize(Integer.parseInt(initialSize));
        pooledDataSource.setMaxPoolSize(Integer.parseInt(maxPoolSize));
        pooledDataSource.setMinPoolSize(Integer.parseInt(minPoolSize));
        pooledDataSource.setSQLForValidateConnection(TEST_SQL);
        pooledDataSource.setValidateConnectionOnBorrow(Boolean.TRUE);
        pooledDataSource
                .setConnectionWaitTimeout(CONNECTION_WAIT_TIMEOUT_SECS);
        // pooledDataSource.setConnectionPoolName(poolName);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Unable to parse passed numeric value", e);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        LOGGER.error("exception creating data pool", e);
    }

    LOGGER.info("Setting up datasource for user:{} and databaseUrl:{}",
            databaseUsername, databaseUrl);
    return this.pooledDataSource;
}

@Bean(name = "dialerEntityManagerFactory")
public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean lef = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    lef.setDataSource(dialerDataSource());
    lef.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
    lef.setPackagesToScan("com.nervytech.dialer.db.domain");
    lef.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());
    lef.setPersistenceUnitName("dialerPersistenceUnit");
    lef.afterPropertiesSet();
    return lef.getObject();
}

@Bean(name = "dialerTransactionManager")
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory());
    return transactionManager;
}

Properties additionalProperties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect",
            "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");     
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql","true");

    return properties;
}

/**
 * Sets the environment.
 * 
 * @param environment
 *            the new environment
 */
@Autowired
public void setEnvironment(Environment environment) {

    this.environment = environment;
}
```

}

pom.xml,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.nervytech</groupId>
<artifactId>dialer</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>dialer</name>
<description>Nervy Dialer</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>



<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <start-class>com.nervytech.dialer.DialerApplication</start-class>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-integration</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId> 
        </dependency> -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-ws</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-integration-mail</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        <!-- <version>3.2.1</version>-->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ucp</artifactId>
        <version>11.2.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <!-- <version>5.1.6</version>-->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.json-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Not sure why this error is still coming though the dialect is there in the dialerEntityManagerFactory.

Thanks,
Baskar.S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further research, I found a solution and wanted to share.
Below is my property file.

```
application.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource
application.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbName 
application.datasource.username=root
application.datasource.password=root
application.datasource.initialSize=5
application.datasource.maxPoolSize=5
application.datasource.minPoolSize=5
```

There was some empty space after the database name in the datasource.url. Spring will throw such error if the database connection is not established during the startup.

But adding the below property will let you start Spring boot though the db connection is not established.

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect= org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect

But Spring boot will reestablish the connection on the fly whenever the DB connection could be established after the startup.

Thanks,
Baskar.S